# WebMock simulate failing API (no internet, timeout ++)

Tags: ruby, rspec, webmock

I am trying to simulate unexpected behaviour from a web api, such as not finding the server and timeouts, using webmock.

What would be the best way to do this? All I can think of is to do something like this:

```
stubbed_request = stub_request(:get, "#{host}/api/something.json").
with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
to_return(:status => [500, "Internal Server Error"])
```

That should work for things like 404 etc., but how can I test **timeouts**, **server not found/offline server**, and **no internet connection**?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After some digging I found some solutions to this.

Apparently you can change the `to_return(...)` to `to_timeout`, which will throw a timeout error. You can also have `to_raise(StandardError)`. For full reference, see https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#raising-timeout-errors.

Timeout, or **server not found**, example:

```
stubbed_request = stub_request(:get, "#{host}/api/something.json").
with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
to_timeout
```

Raise StandardError, or **no internet**/other exception, example:

```
stubbed_request = stub_request(:get, "#{host}/api/something.json").
with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
to_raise(StandardError)

#Error example 2:
stubbed_request = stub_request(:get, "#{host}/api/something.json").
with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
to_raise("My special error")
```

There you go, not too hard after all.

---

I have no idea how I didn't find this the first time. Anyway, hope this helps someone out one day.

Comment: This did help, shame on me for not finding `to_raise` and `to_timeout` sooner. Thanks!

Comment: Strange, if I use `to_timeout` I cant avoid a `RestClient::RequestTimeout` being thrown and my test errors out. If I use `to_raise` in any fashion, I get a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`.

Comment: To be honest it sounds like you have a bug in your code :/

Answer (score 1):

Came across this question and decided to add supportive materials. According to a discussion in WebMock issue (https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/16), the timeout can be simulated in two ways.

**The first way is two use .to_raise(e)**:

```
stubbed_request = stub_request(:get, "#{host}/api/something.json").
with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User- 
Agent'=>'Ruby'}).to_raise(e)
```

Where **e** is a library specific timeout exception. 
quotation: "The whole point of WebMock is to be HTTP client library independent so to_timeout should work with every library.
The problem is that different libraries return different errors, ie Net::HTTP return Ruby Timeout::Error while HTTPClient raises HTTPClient:: TimeoutError.
This behavior can be replicated in WebMock but the error handling code will have to be different any time you change the library."

**The second way is to use the following sample:**

```
stub_request(:any, 'www.example.net').to_timeout
RestClient.post('www.example.net', 'abc')    # ===> RestClient::RequestTimeout
```

Here is the original source: https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/16