# Simulate empty response if server is down

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockserver

I have 2 mockservices returning success and failure responses based on request body.
Now I need to simulate an empty response if the server is down or unavailable.

How can this be done in Java ?

Comment: If the server is "down" then your client would get a timeout error trying to connect, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the timeout of your client socket to a very short value to simulate timing out trying to connect to the server.

Here's a [question showing how to set a socket timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969760/setting-a-timeout-for-socket-operations). Most HTTP clients let you provide config properties for the underlying TCP socket.

There are also test utilities to help with this, such as [WebMock, explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552239/webmock-simulate-failing-api-no-internet-timeout).